# Angular 10 - Navigator router not working ok

Tags: angular

I have a general Angular routes configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `students`, loadChildren: () =>
      import('./@pages/students/students.module').then(m => m.StudentModule),
  },
  { path: ``, redirectTo: `mainPage`, pathMatch: `full` }
];
```

And I have another path file for the "StudentsModule" module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:  ``, 
    component: StudentsComponent,
  },
  {
    path:  `students/:idstudent`, 
    component: StudentsTableComponent,
  },
];
```

When I click a button to component template "StudentsComponent", I want to go to

```
this.router.navigate(['/students/' + this.idStudent]);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'students/3'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'students/3'
```

http://localhost:4200/students, loads component: StudentsComponent

http://localhost:4200/students/3, should be loading component: StudentsTableComponent

What could be the problem? thanks

Comment: use this.router.navigate(['students/' + this.idStudent]);
remove "/" in students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```js
 this.router.navigate(['/students/' + this.idStudent]);
```

OR

```js
 this.router.navigate([`/students/${this.idStudent}`]);
```

#### Routes: `StudentsModule`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:  ``, 
    component: StudentsComponent,
  },
  {
    path:  `:idstudent`, 
    component: StudentsTableComponent,
  },
];
```

If not solve with this please check in `StudentsModule` File `StudentTableComponent` is added or not in declaration.

Comment: Yes, StudentTableComponent is declared in StudentsModule, but I can't get it to work with your suggestion :(, I get the same error.

Comment: It works ok, in the a router file of StudentsModule I have changed: path: `students/: idstudent`, to path:`:idstudent`

Comment: @Eladerezador i have updated my code if done then upvote please.